# Set values on the diagonal of pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe I would like to se the diagonal to 0

```
import numpy
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(5,5))
df

Out[6]:
     0           1           2           3               4
0    0.536596    0.674319    0.032815    0.908086    0.215334
1    0.735022    0.954506    0.889162    0.711610    0.415118
2    0.119985    0.979056    0.901891    0.687829    0.947549
3    0.186921    0.899178    0.296294    0.521104    0.638924
4    0.354053    0.060022    0.275224    0.635054    0.075738
5 rows × 5 columns
```

now I want to set the diagonal to 0:

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        if i==j:
            df.loc[i,j] = 0
df
Out[9]:
     0           1           2           3           4
0    0.000000    0.674319    0.032815    0.908086    0.215334
1    0.735022    0.000000    0.889162    0.711610    0.415118
2    0.119985    0.979056    0.000000    0.687829    0.947549
3    0.186921    0.899178    0.296294    0.000000    0.638924
4    0.354053    0.060022    0.275224    0.635054    0.000000
5 rows × 5 columns
```

but there must be a more pythonic way than that!?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
In [21]: df.values[[np.arange(df.shape[0])]*2] = 0

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.000000  0.931374  0.604412  0.863842  0.280339
1  0.531528  0.000000  0.641094  0.204686  0.997020
2  0.137725  0.037867  0.000000  0.983432  0.458053
3  0.594542  0.943542  0.826738  0.000000  0.753240
4  0.357736  0.689262  0.014773  0.446046  0.000000
```

Note that this will only work if `df` has the same number of rows as columns. Another way which will work for arbitrary shapes is to use [np.fill_diagonal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html):

```
In [36]: np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 0)
```

Comment: This solution does work for me with the suggested toy data but fails with my own larger matrix.

Comment: @PhilippSchwarz One nice thing about `np.fill_diagonal` is that it will work on any DataFrame or matrix that you can fit in RAM without using any more memory. The "fill" assignments happen efficiently "in place" in memory and leave the `index` and `columns` and other attributes of the DataFrame intact.

Comment: The first solution throws a `FutureWarning` now, as non-tuple sequences for multidimensional indexing are deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

Using `np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 1)` Is the easiest, but you need to make sure your columns all have the same data type I had a mixture of np.float64 and python floats and it would only effect the numpy values. to fix you have to cast everything to numpy.

Answer (score 5):

This solution is vectorized and very fast and, unlike the other suggested solution, works for any column names and  size of df matrix.

```
def pd_fill_diagonal(df_matrix, value=0): 
    mat = df_matrix.values
    n = mat.shape[0]
    mat[range(n), range(n)] = value
    return pd.DataFrame(mat)
```

Performance on Dataframe of 507 columns and rows

```
% timeit pd_fill_diagonal(df, 0)
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 145 µs per loop

Answer (score 4):

Both approaches in [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24475214/2858145) assume that labels are irrelevant (they operate on the underlying values).

The OP code works with `.loc` and so is label based instead (i.e. put a 0 on cells in row-column with same labels, rather than in cells located on the diagonal - admittedly, this is irrelevant in the specific example given, in which labels are just positions).

Being in need of the "label-based" diagonal filling (working with a `DataFrame` describing an incomplete adjacency matrix), the simplest approach I could come up with was:

```
def pd_fill_diagonal(df, value):
    idces = df.index.intersection(df.columns)
    stacked = df.stack(dropna=False)
    stacked.update(pd.Series(value,
                             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idces,
                                                              idces])))
    df.loc[:, :] = stacked.unstack()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way with `np.identity`

```
df.where(np.identity(df.shape[0]) != 1,0)
```

Output:

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.000000  0.674319  0.032815  0.908086  0.215334
1  0.735022  0.000000  0.889162  0.711610  0.415118
2  0.119985  0.979056  0.000000  0.687829  0.947549
3  0.186921  0.899178  0.296294  0.000000  0.638924
4  0.354053  0.060022  0.275224  0.635054  0.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish this is to get the anti-identity matrix and multiply your dataframe with it.

`df * abs(np.eye(len(df))-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack that worked for me:

```
def set_diag(self, values): 
    n = min(len(self.index), len(self.columns))
    self.values[[np.arange(n)] * 2] = values
pd.DataFrame.set_diag = set_diag

x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5))
x.set_diag(0)
```

Comment: How is that different from `numpy.fill_diagonal`? Also, adding fields to existing library types is not a good thing to advise.

Answer (score -1):

All the answers given which rely on modifying `DataFrame.values` are depending on undocumented behavior.  The `values` property is allowed to return a copy of data, but the solutions that modify `values` are assuming it returns a view. Sometimes it does return a view, but the pandas documentation makes no guarantees about when it will.