# Removing matching index values from dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, for-loop

`df`:

```
         0         1         2 
0 0.0481948 0.1054251 0.1153076 
1 0.0407258 0.0890868 0.0974378 
2 0.0172071 0.0376403 0.0411687
etc.
```

I would like to remove all values in which the x and y titles/values of the dataframe are equal, therefore, my expected output would be something like:

```
         0         1         2 
0 NaN       0.1054251 0.1153076 
1 0.0407258 NaN       0.0974378 
2 0.0172071 0.0376403 NaN
etc.
```

As shown, the values of (0,0), (1,1), (2,2) and so on, have been removed/replaced.

I thought of looping through the index as followed:

```
for (idx, row) in df.iterrows():
    if (row.index) == ???
```

But don't know where to carry on or whether it's even the right approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the diagonal:

```
In [11]: df.iloc[[np.arange(len(df))] * 2] = np.nan

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
          0         1         2
0       NaN  0.105425  0.115308
1  0.040726       NaN  0.097438
2  0.017207  0.037640       NaN
```

Comment: Thank You. Why `* 2`? :)

Comment: @LearningToPython the * 2 is because what you really want is `df.iloc[[np.arange(3), np.arange(3)]]` and this saves a little bit of typing!

Comment: Okay, Thanks! I'm a newbie, how would `[np.arange(3), np.arange(3)]` work? ;/ Sorry

Comment: @LearningToPython it's fancy indexing, and one of the great things in pandas/numpy see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: Seems complicated ;-) I'll try understand. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

@AndyHayden's answer is really cool and taught me something.  However, it depends on `iloc` and that the array is square and that everything is in the same order.

I generalized the concept here

Consider the data frame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, list('abcd'), list('xcya'))

df

   x  c  y  a
a  1  1  1  1
b  1  1  1  1
c  1  1  1  1
d  1  1  1  1
```

Then we use numpy broadcasting and `np.where` to perform the same fancy index assignment:

```
ij = np.where(df.index.values[:, None] == df.columns.values)

df.iloc[list(map(list, ij))] = 0

df

   x  c  y  a
a  1  1  1  0
b  1  1  1  1
c  1  0  1  1
d  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: I am surprised that this `df.loc[[(df.index & df.columns)] * 2]` or a variant doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

n is number of rows/columns

```
df.values[[np.arange(n)]*2] = np.nan
```

or

```
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, np.nan)
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24475214/

Comment: Oh, Great. Why `* 2`?

Comment: I'm referring to [np.arange(n)]*2] ;-) by the way

Comment: Note: fill_diagonal won't always works, as sometimes df.values will be a copy. In fact same is true in both your examples. E.g. this happens for mixed data types.

Comment: For example, do `df.iloc[0, 2] = 'a'` before trying.