# Transform a dataframe for network graphing

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a dataframe like so:

```
ID  | Node 1 | Node 2 | Node 3
a   |   1    |    0   |   1
b   |   0    |    1   |   1
c   |   1    |    0   |   0
d   |   1    |    1   |   1
e   |   0    |    1   |   1
```

I want to change it so that I can turn it into a network chart, where connections between nodes are the amount of times an ID is indicated for both of them:

```
Node A | Node B | Weight |
Node 1 | Node 2 |    1   |
Node 1 | Node 3 |    2   |
Node 2 | Node 3 |    3   |
```

Comment: Is this only for three columns? Or are you intending to use it for more?

Comment: For more - ideally it would work with a dynamic number of columns (up to 60)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on [Tai's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49079799/190597), 
you could obtain the desired DataFrame using

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_weights(df):
    df2 = df.filter(regex='Node')
    nodes = df2.columns
    arr = df2.values
    m = np.dot(arr.T, arr).astype(float)
    idx = np.tril_indices(m.shape[0])   
    m[idx] = np.nan
    result = pd.DataFrame(m, columns=nodes, index=nodes)
    result = result.stack()
    result = result.astype(int)
    result = result.reset_index()
    result.columns = ['Node A', 'Node B', 'Weights']
    return result

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 'Node 1': [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 'Node 2': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 'Node 3': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]})
result = get_weights(df)
print(result)
```

which yields

```
   Node A  Node B  Weight
0  Node 1  Node 2       1
1  Node 1  Node 3       2
2  Node 2  Node 3       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a edge-list form

```
Node A | Node B | Weight |
Node 1 | Node 2 |    1   |
Node 1 | Node 3 |    2   |
Node 2 | Node 3 |    3   |
```

you can also calculate a co-occurance/adjancency matrix to represent the relationship you are interested. It can be constructed using a dot product. alko's already gave an answer in pandas in [Constructing a co-occurrence matrix in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574257/constructing-a-co-occurrence-matrix-in-python-pandas)

I modify alko's answer using `numpy`

```
m = df.values.T.dot(df.values)
np.fill_diagonal(m, 0)

# array([[0, 1, 2],
#       [1, 0, 3],
#       [2, 3, 0]])
# You can use nx.from_numpy_matrix to construct a graph
# m[i, j] is the number of co-occurance between node i and node j.
```

One part that I am not fond of alko's answer is that it tries to change the diagonal part of an dataframe, say `df`, by changing `df.values`. Changing `df.values` directly to change `df` should not be promoted because sometimes `df.values` returns a copy while sometimes a view. See my previous question [Will changes in DataFrame.values always modify the values in the data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201521/will-changes-in-dataframe-values-always-modify-the-values-in-the-data-frame) for more information.

If one want to follow alko's pandas method, one can replace `np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 0)` with

`df = df - np.eye(len(df)) * np.diagonal(df)`

Answer (score 1):

## Dataframe to an adjacency matrix

You can iterate through your dataframe to create a numpy array:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'node_1': [1,0,1,1,0], 
                   'node_2':[0,1,0,1,1], 
                   'node_3':[1,1,0,1,1]})

# Array dimension
l = len(df.columns)
# empty matrice
mat = np.zeros((l,l))

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    positions = np.where(row)[0]
    if len(positions)>1:
        for comb in combinations(positions,2):
            i,j = comb
            mat[i,j] += 1
            mat[j,i] += 1

mat
```

`array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.]])`

## Networkx graph from numpy adjency matrix

```
G = nx.Graph(mat)
G.edges(data=True)
```

[out]: `EdgeDataView([(0, 1, {'weight': 1.0}), (0, 2, {'weight': 2.0}), (1, 2, {'weight': 3.0})])`

Answer (score 0):

You can first use itertools to find all the combinations, then find the weight for each pair.

```
import itertools
(
     pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(df.set_index('ID').columns,2)), 
                  columns=['Node A', 'Node B'])
     .assign(Weight=lambda y: y.apply(lambda x: df[[x['Node A'],x['Node B']]]
                                                .all(1).sum(), axis=1))
)

Out[39]: 
   Node A  Node B  Weight
0  Node 1  Node 2       1
1  Node 1  Node 3       2
2  Node 2  Node 3       3
```