# Pandas dataframe value are automatically updating without any direct modification

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have assigned a variable `aae` with one column of pandas dataframe. If any modification is made on variable `aae` then the values of pandas dataframe get automatically modified. Please look at this example:

[image: Screenshot of the code]

modification in `aae` makes an automatic change in pandas dataframe value without any direct change made in `df['Absorption_Angstrom_Exponent_440-870nm']`. If `aae` is modified then pandas dataframe `df` should not be changed. Please help me with this automatic update issue with pandas dataframe.

Comment: aae is a reference to the df dataframe. if you need to keep them distinct. add .copy() when assigning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201521/will-changes-in-dataframe-values-always-modify-the-values-in-the-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.values` but `to_numpy(copy=True)`:

```
a = df.to_numpy(copy=True)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=int))

a = df.to_numpy(copy=True)

a[0, 0] = 999
```

output:

```
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
```

Same thing with `.values`:

```
     0  1  2
0  999  0  0
1    0  0  0
2    0  0  0
```