# Fill the diagonal of Pandas DataFrame with elements from Pandas Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, linear-algebra

Given a pandas `Series` with an index:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3],index=['a','b','c'])
```

**How can a Series be used to fill the diagonal entries of an empty DataFrame in pandas version >= 0.23.0?**

The resulting DataFrame would look like:

```
  a b c
a 1 0 0
b 0 2 0
c 0 0 3
```

There is [a prior similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475094/set-values-on-the-diagonal-of-pandas-dataframe) which will fill the diagonal with the same value, my question is asking to fill the diagonal with varying values from a Series.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First create `DataFrame` and then [`numpy.fill_diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html):

```
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3],index=['a','b','c'])

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=s.index, columns=s.index, dtype=s.dtype)

np.fill_diagonal(df.values, s)
print (df)
   a  b  c
a  1  0  0
b  0  2  0
c  0  0  3
```

Another solution is create empty `2d` array, add values to diagonal and last use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
arr = np.zeros((len(s), len(s)), dtype=s.dtype)
np.fill_diagonal(arr, s)

print (arr)
[[1 0 0]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 0 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=s.index, columns=s.index)
print (df)
   a  b  c
a  1  0  0
b  0  2  0
c  0  0  3
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about directly doing it with Pandas, but you can do this easily enough if you don't mind using [`numpy.diag()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) to build the diagonal data matrix for your series and then plugging that into a DataFrame:

```
diag_data = np.diag(s)  # don't need s.as_matrix(), turns out
df = pd.DataFrame(diag_data, index=s.index, columns=s.index)

   a  b  c
a  1  0  0
b  0  2  0
c  0  0  3
```

In one line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(s),
                  index=s.index,
                  columns=s.index)
```

Timing comparison with a Series made from a random array of 10000 elements:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10000), index=np.arange(10000))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(s), ...)
173 ms ± 2.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20 loops each)

df = pd.DataFrame(0, ...)
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, s)
212 ms ± 909 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20 loops each)

mat = np.zeros(...)
np.fill_diagonal(mat, s)
df = pd.DataFrame(mat, ...)
175 ms ± 3.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20 loops each)
```

It looks like the first and third option shown here are essentially the same, while the middle option is the slowest.