# iterate in series with multiindex and delete rows if value is XX

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I build a correlationmatrix and want to delete all labels and values under XX
I am building a series so i can iterate over the values but i dont know how to delete the raws.
the next step is to convert it back to a dataframe. Maybe you know a better way.

Here a mini-example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  

data = np.random.rand(4,4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['varname1', 'varname2', 'varname3', 'varname4'], 
                  columns = ['longname1', 'longname2', 'longname3', 'longname4'])

corr = abs(df.corr().stack())
corr = corr[corr.index.get_level_values(0) != corr.index.get_level_values(1)] #delete doubles

for i in range(len(corr.keys())):
    if corr[i] <= 0.2:
        corr = corr.drop(corr[i]) # how can i delete the raws
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain another mask by `&` for bitwise `AND` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), for reshape back add [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
np.random.seed(2020)
data = np.random.rand(4,4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['varname1', 'varname2', 'varname3', 'varname4'], 
                  columns = ['longname1', 'longname2', 'longname3', 'longname4'])

print (df)
          longname1  longname2  longname3  longname4
varname1   0.986277   0.873392   0.509746   0.271836
varname2   0.336919   0.216954   0.276477   0.343316
varname3   0.862159   0.156700   0.140887   0.757080
varname4   0.736325   0.355663   0.341093   0.666803

corr = df.corr().stack().abs()
m1 = corr.index.get_level_values(0) != corr.index.get_level_values(1)
m2 = corr > 0.2
corr = corr[m1 & m2].unstack()
print (corr)
           longname1  longname2  longname3  longname4
longname1        NaN   0.584300   0.326267        NaN
longname2   0.584300        NaN   0.937580   0.641093
longname3   0.326267   0.937580        NaN   0.720851
longname4        NaN   0.641093   0.720851        NaN
```

Another idea is replace missing values by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and then fill diagonal values by `NaN` by this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24475214)

```
df1 = df.corr().abs()
df1 = df1.where(df1 > 0.2)
np.fill_diagonal(df1.values, np.nan)
print (df1)
           longname1  longname2  longname3  longname4
longname1        NaN   0.584300   0.326267        NaN
longname2   0.584300        NaN   0.937580   0.641093
longname3   0.326267   0.937580        NaN   0.720851
longname4        NaN   0.641093   0.720851        NaN
```

Comment: ty, this is exactly what i am looking for. but can you explain me plz what [m1 & m2] is doing. is it comparing the 2 series? can you plz give me llink to the documentation :)

Comment: @credenco - link for boolean indexing is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 1):

you have almost got it.
simply change your last code from

```
for i in range(len(corr.keys())):
    if corr[i] <= 0.2:
        corr = corr.drop(corr[i]) # how can i delete the raws
```

to

```
corr = corr[corr > 0.2]
```

then you get it